# How to fetch single data in Angularjs with Laravel5

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I face an issue while retrieving single row/data from angular to html. I need to print the title. Below is the code of angular controller (partial):

```
    vm.showJoke = function(joke){
  console.log(joke);

  $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/jokes/' + joke, {
        //body: joke.joke,
        //user_id: $rootScope.currentUser.id
        //user_id: localstorageUser.role_id
    }).success(function(response) {
      //console.log(response.data.joke);
      vm.jokes_show = response.data.joke;
      console.log(vm.jokes_show);
        $scope.MessageAll = 'Joke shows! ';
    }).error(function(){
      console.log("error");
      $scope.MessageAll = 'Please try again';
    });
}
```

Below is my HTML codes:

```
<span ng-hide="showEnabled">
                <a href="#jokes" ng-click="showEnabled=!showEnabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" data-ng-click="jokes.showJoke(joke.joke_id)"></span></a>
            </span>


            <span ng-show="showEnabled" style="background-color:powderblue;">
                    <p style="background-color:powderblue;" ng-model="jokes_show"></p>
            </span>
```

Here is the response I found below:

```
{joke_id: 3, joke: "Quia in enim voluptates neque. Ullam eligendi ipsu…iente qui perferendis libero. Ut aut qui sint et.", submitted_by: "admin"}
```

joke
:
"Quia in enim voluptates neque. Ullam eligendi ipsum eaque magni sit fugit in. Voluptate sapiente qui perferendis libero. Ut aut qui sint et."
joke_id
:
3
submitted_by
:
"admin"

See the image for the same too.

[image]

Your help most welcome.

Comment: How does your `response` object look like? Please add this.

Comment: {joke_id: 2, joke: "2Excepturi officia velit enim enim nihil. Sed nam … accusantium delectus nemo. Harum ipsam est sint.", submitted_by: null}
joke
:
"2Excepturi officia velit enim enim nihil. Sed nam qui omnis perspiciatis. Molestiae excepturi explicabo accusantium delectus nemo. Harum ipsam est sint."
joke_id
:
2
submitted_by
:
null

Comment: @lin - see above, this is the response I received.

Comment: @lin - for this code `response.data;` , the above response come.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and insert your response as a code block, thanks.

Comment: @lin - question edited and added the response code there.

Comment: @lin - any idea Lin?